# Batch file loop with findstr

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
rem Let findstr to find the LINE you want (only once):
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "to_timestamp" t1.txt') do set "_line=%%a"
SET _line2=%_line:*to_timestamp=%
SET _line3=%_line2:*)=%
set _rep_str=('07-10-13 07:07:29','%%d-%%m-%%y %%h:%%i:%%s')
CALL SET _result=%%_line:%_line2%=%%
CALL SET _result2=%%_line2:%_line3%=%%
CALL SET _result=%%_line:%_line2%=%%
CALL SET _result=%_result:to_timestamp=STR_TO_DATE%
echo %_result%%_rep_str%%_line3% >> Output.txt

::echo %_rep_str% >> Output.txt
::echo %_line3% >> Output.txt
PAUSE
```

Above code is working for the first line // occurrence of **findstr** but I want to perform the same operation on each line of the text file.

How to do that?

Comment: Can you give us some sample input and expected output? Might make understanding your problem easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is more than one line that matchs, the way you have coded the file, only the last occurrence will be processed (previous values are overwritten during loop)

Separate you code, create a subroutine and call this subroutine for each occurrence

```
@echo off
    rem Let findstr to find the LINE you want (only once):
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "to_timestamp" t1.txt') do call :doWork "%%a"
    ....
    ....
    PAUSE
    exit /B

:doWork
    SET "_line=%~1"
    SET _line2=%_line:*to_timestamp=%
    SET _line3=%_line2:*)=%
    set _rep_str=('07-10-13 07:07:29','%%d-%%m-%%y %%h:%%i:%%s')
    CALL SET _result=%%_line:%_line2%=%%
    CALL SET _result2=%%_line2:%_line3%=%%
    CALL SET _result=%%_line:%_line2%=%%
    CALL SET _result=%_result:to_timestamp=STR_TO_DATE%
    echo %_result%%_rep_str%%_line3% >> Output.txt

    ::echo %_rep_str% >> Output.txt
    ::echo %_line3% >> Output.txt

    goto :EOF
```